# Finding a bound

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to show that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{ne^{x/n}-1}{n^3+1}}$ converges uniformly with $x\in(2,4)$.

My instinct is to use the Weierstrass M-test, but I'm having trouble coming up with a bound.  Any hints/suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

What is the maximum possible value of $e^{x/n}$ for $2<x<4$ and $n\ge1$?

Answer (score 0):

For $x\in (2,4)$,

$$\left|\frac{ne^{x/n} - 1}{n^3 + 1}\right| \le \frac{ne^{x/n} + 1}{n^3 + 1} \le \frac{ne^4 + 1}{n^3} =\frac{e^4}{n^2} + \frac{1}{n^3}.$$

Now use the fact that the series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ and $\sum_{n =1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3}$ converge.